# Displaying a list of jobs using a function

Tags: java, function, lambda

I am studying lambda. but I have a problem to display the results.

```
public class JavaTest {

public static Function<String, String> function2() {
    return str -> {return str.replace("programmer", "engineer");};
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Person> results = new ArrayList<Person>();
    
    results.add(new Person("Elsdon", "Jaycob","Java programmer","male",43,2000));
    results.add(new Person("Tamsen", "Brittany","Java programmer","female",23,1500));
    results.add(new Person("Floyd", "Donny","Java programmer","male",33,1800));
    
    //results.stream().map(function2()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

but When I tried to debug my codes, there's something problem in `map`.

I want to know how to use `function` without error.
Any reply is thankful.

Comment: The input to the `map()` function is a `Person`, not a `String`, so you cannot do that. Besides, who did you expect the compiler to know that it's field #3 that needs to be replaced? Re-think what you're trying to do.

Comment: One way to do this, assuming `Person` has appropriate `withXxx()` helper methods, is: `func = function2(); results2 = results.stream().map(p -> p.withTitle(func.apply(p.getTitle()))).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a `Person` class:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private String familyName;
    private String jobTitle;
    // Other attributes and setter/getter methods
}
```

Now you have two ways:

1- Override toString() method of `Person` class:

```
@Override 
public String toString() {
    return this.name + " " + this.familyName + " " + this.jobTitle;
}
```

and then change your `function2()` as below:

```
public static Function<Person> function2() {
    return p -> {return p.toString().replace("programmer", "engineer");};
}
```

2- Or you can change only `jobTitle`:

```
public static Function<Person> function2() {
    return p -> {return p.getJobTitle().replace("programmer", "engineer");};
}
```